# Native Base Text vs React Native Text

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, native-base

I can't decide if I should stick to React Native Text components or Native base text components n my project. Is there an advantage of one over the other?

Are there more use cases of one than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source code for [`Text.js`](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Text.js) for Native Base.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Text as RNText } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { connectStyle } from 'native-base-shoutem-theme';
```

It uses the native components of React-native. There's one extra property: `uppercase`. Keep your project consistent, use Native Base's component whenever possible.

Comment: Why Native Base's tho? Why is it preferred over React Native Text?

Comment: In my opinion, is to keep a convention in the project. I don't want one developer importing Text from react-native in one file and Text from Native base in another file.

Comment: I understand that but my concern is that is there any advantage of Native Base vs RN Text?

Comment: No, but if I have Native Base in my project, I would use that.